# How do I selectively merge files from branch into master in git?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a test branch `test` that was created several days ago. There was a change made to a file `file.py` in `master` since then. I need to merge only this change (and nothing else) from `master` to `test`. What is the right sequence of commands to do it? I presume the first one is

```
git checkout test
```

but then what? I want to be 100% sure that no other changes get merged into `test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `cherry-pick` command if you know the exact commit in your "master" branch that changed file.py:

```
git checkout test
git cherry-pick COMMIT_SHA
```

Otherwise you can do something like:

```
git checkout test
git checkout master -- file.py
git commit -m "Your message"
```

Edit: I had the branches mixed up. I corrected them.

Comment: Ok thanks. So when I do `git commit -m "Your message"`, is this going to commit into `test`?

Comment: It will commit into "master"

Comment: Ah crud. I just realized I had the branches backwards, will amend my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also check out individual files in git. So, after `git checkout test`,

you can do

`git checkout master path/to/your/file.py`

and have just that file from the other branch :-)